# Versioning Strategy for an ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, svn

I am building an MVC application with multiple layers (Class library projects for different tiers in a solution where ASP.NET MVC app runs as the start up project), and one of the concerns is to track the build version. (So that the QA team can mark defects against a version)

The application is hosted on an SVN repository. Currently the revision number of the web application folder is used as the build number.

The issue is when changes occur on other folders the revision number does not get updated.

TeamCity is used for CI

Questions

1. What is the industry best practice?
2. Should we go with SVN revisions or our own build numbering mechanism?
3. Should we consider using TeamCity build number, if so how to get it to a text file?

Comment: I feel like this question is better suited for [Programmers StackExchange](https://programmers.stackexchange.com/). Also, be aware that it's a question that will likely attract highly-opinionated answers and may be closed for this reason. You might have to re-word it so that it can be answered more directly.

Comment: Have you ever used SVN tags? Thats what we do to keep a history of everything